# Java Grpc: invalidate dns cache

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have a grpc client pointing to a url which resolves to 2 IP addresses.
The problem is when one server node goes down and then gets back, it's not picked by the grpc client and all the load goes to a single node.

I tried recommendation to change `networkaddress.cache.ttl` propetty but it didn't help.
My code (in Scala)

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "30")
System.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "30")
val channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).nameResolverFactory(
      new DnsNameResolverProvider).usePlaintext().build
val client = MyServiceGrpc.newStub(channel)
```

grpc version: 1.32.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that DNS returns both IPs all the time (probably shuffled), then the problem is not the DNS cache. The problem is that gRPC has a working connection and so won't choose to reconnect and won't perform DNS queries.

You should configure your server with [`MAX_CONNECTION_AGE`](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A9-server-side-conn-mgt.md#proposal) to force clients to reconnect occasionally to rebalance the load. When clients are disconnected from the server they trigger a new DNS resolution, so this can also be used to find new addresses (although reconnections do not wait for the DNS resolution to complete).

In Java, `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` is available via [`NettyServerBuilder.maxConnectionAge()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyServerBuilder.html#maxConnectionAge-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

```java
NettyServerBuilder.forPort(yourPort)
    .maxConnectionAge(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    ....
```

You want to use as large of age as you can accept. With a time like 30 minutes, then each client will rebalance every 30 minutes. So after 15 minutes of the server restarting that server would have ¼ of the load and after 30 minutes it would have roughly ½.

Comment: thanks for your response, I saw this option too. For me it looks like a hack: it's not a responsibility of individual server instance to initiate closing of the connection. 
I added `defaultLoadBalancingPolicy` parameter (see my response) and it seems to help. Could you please comment on it?

Comment: `round_robin` will cause each client to connect to each server all the time. That may be a good approach for you. But if the addresses returned by DNS change, you'd still need `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` for the client to notice those new addresses. This is how DNS-based infrastructure works; things like HTTP just create connections almost constantly.

Comment: sorry if this is off-topic, but is there a fundamental reason why the client can't refresh the list of addresses from time to time and rebalance workload by itself?

Comment: In high-scale deployments, it is common for DNS servers to return a subset of the server addresses. Those servers return different results every response. There's also the question of how frequently the client should poll. The "client polls" strategy is unhelpful for pick_first, as the client will continue favoring its established connection. `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` is strongly necessary for L4 load balancing and can be used for these other approaches as well. It also avoids hard-coding configuration in clients.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that configuring load-balancing policy does the job:

```
NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin").usePlaintext().build()
```

Comment: Only configuring round robin LB policy + k8s headless service wont be able to detect new pod IP (if you scale up). Some hack needed on server side, we need to set max_connection_age_ms and max_connection_age_grace_ms